# Favicon not displaying on drupal websited hosted on IIS server

Tags: drupal, iis, favicon

Everything is said in the title. I have put my favicon file in the root of the server. But I haven t any favicon displaying. Could somebody help me ? thank you in advance for answering

Answer (score 1):

[Drupal favicons belong in not your root folder, but your theme's folder.](http://www.ehow.com/how_8363062_replace-favicon-drupal.html)

Answer (score 1):

Also you need to enable it at admin/appearance/settings/urtheme there you will need to change **the Shortcut icon settings** settings